# Instagram API: how to make in popular feed see user and likes

Tags: php, javascript, api, instagram

I have this code and I want to write before every photo a text and I don't know where to write. By the way, I want to know every photo which is uploaded likes and users.

```
function loadFeed() {
    var param = {access_token:access_token};
    cmd(param, onPhotoLoaded);
}

function cmd(param, callback) {
    //popular
    var cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?callback=?';
    $.getJSON(cmdURL, param, callback);
}

function onPhotoLoaded(data) {
    if(data.meta.code == 200) {
        var photos = data.data;

        if(photos.length > 0) {
            for (var key in photos ){
                var photo = photos[key];
                $('<div id=p' + photo.id + '></div>').addClass('photoWrapper').appendTo('#panel');

                var str = '<img id="' + photo.id + '" src="' + photo.images.standard_resolution.url + '" width="100%">';
                $('<div></div>').addClass('photo').html(str).appendTo('#p' + photo.id);

                $('#' + photo.id).load(function() {
                    $('#p' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
                });

            }
        }else{
            alert('empty');
        }

    }else{
        alert(data.meta.error_message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you are looking for is in the photo object.

http://jsfiddle.net/AbU7a/

```
function loadFeed() {
    cmd({access_token:'11007611.f59def8.4f942a67c9174159a1601a037490d3ea'}, onPhotoLoaded);
}

function cmd(param, callback) {
    //popular
    var cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?callback=?';
    $.getJSON(cmdURL, param, callback);
}

function onPhotoLoaded(data) {
    if(data.meta.code == 200) {
        var photos = data.data;
console.log(photos);
        if(photos.length > 0) {
            for (var key in photos ){
                var photo = photos[key];
                $('<div id=p' + photo.id + '></div>').addClass('photoWrapper').appendTo('#panel');

                var str = '<p>likes: '+ photo.likes.count +'</p><img id="' + photo.id + '" src="' + photo.images.standard_resolution.url + '" width="50">';
                $('<div></div>').addClass('photo').html(str).appendTo('#p' + photo.id);

                $('#' + photo.id).load(function() {
                    $('#p' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
                });

            }
        }else{
            alert('empty');
        }

    }else{
        alert(data.meta.error_message);
    }
}

loadFeed();
```

View your console (differs depending on your browser) it will show you the data you can get from the photo object.

I started you off by adding the likes count.